# Android Studio - Soft keyboard 'Enter' making text disappear

Tags: android

When I'm using my app to enter text into an editview, when I click the Enter button on the soft keyboard the text entered is disappearing. Ideally I would like the app to go to the next edittext box when the user clicks the button as it does on a different form, however the XML is the same for the button so unsure as to why there is a difference

To try getting the enter button move to the next edit text I've tried inputting the following into the XML but had no luck so far

```
android:imeOpions="actionNext";
```

XML For Control As Requested

```
<EditText
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:id="@+id/text_name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:visibility="invisible"
            />
```

Comment: Removed Line above as didn't work

Comment: Share the complete xml for this control

Comment: @Skynet done, see above

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I created a basic activity a simple layout ( shown below). When I press enter in the edit text, it goes to the next edit text.

I added the code you mentioned

```
(android:imeOpions="actionNext";)
```

but I also had to add:

<strike>`android:singleLine="true"`</strike>

**EDIT: singleLine is deprecated.** 
You can simply add

```
android:inputType="text"
```

to your editText.

That worked for me. I think the reason that the line was disappearing was because it was being shifted up and out of the bounds of the textview. The EditText thought you wanted to create a new line. That's my guess.

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
              android:layout_width="match_parent"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:orientation="vertical"
              android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
              android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
              tools:context="com.slipperyslope.aperturelabs.nextfield.NextEditTextActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Example"/>


    <!-- This way works!-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/first_edittext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text"
        />

    <!-- This way works! But it's deprecated-->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/second_edittext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:imeOptions="actionNext"
        android:singleLine="true"
        />

    <!-- dummy edit text just to transition to. -->
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/third_edittext"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

Let me know if this works or if you are still having issues.

Comment: Your right! It wasn't disappearing it was just going out of view
And yeah adding `android:inputType="text"` did change the enter button so that it moves to the next edittext field. Bit strange how I didn't need that on the one in the previous form, bug to report to android I guess